# Cannot find memory leak in my new game?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management, memory-leaks, sdl

I'm making my first game in C++, and it seems that I have a memory leak.

Stack Exchange won't let me post pictures, but I opened the task manager to the "Memory tab", and the memory graph slowly increases while my game is open, and then decreases abruptly when the game is closed.

Right now, my game just includes a ball that can move around and shoot bullets, and displays text using SDL_ttf to show how much ammo is left, which gun is selected, and which wave I am on, which is a static variable from the Main class. However, strangely enough, without even shooting any bullets or pressing any buttons, this memory leak still occurs. I've been making sure I don't have any memory leaks since I started the game, and up until recently there haven't been any. This means that my memory leak is most likely caused by the text being displayed or accessing the static variable, because I don't know exactly how forward declarations work (I don't think).

Since the memory leak happens without pressing any buttons in the game, I figured that it must be triggered in the game loop, so I checked all the function calls and everything in the game loop, which leads me to think that it must be from something in the Player class, specifically in the Update() or renderHUD().

Here's the code from the Player and Main class, I included the headers to make sure that my forward declarations were ok and so you see which pointers I'm using. I didn't include the game loop because all of the function calls that could potentially cause a memory leak are included already. I'm using Visual Studio 2012, with SDL2.

```
#pragma once

#include "GameObject.h"
#include "Bullet.h"
#include "destructive_reasoning.h"
#include "Screen.h"
#include "Magazine.h"
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <sstream>

class Main;

class Player : public GameObject
{
public:

private:
    int* xOffset;
    int* yOffset;
    int gameWidth;
    int gameHeight;

    Screen* screen;

    SDL_Renderer* renderer;

    std::vector<Bullet*> bullets;
    std::vector<Magazine> clips;
    std::vector<std::string> weaponNames;

    bool readyToShoot;

    Weapon weapon;

    TTF_Font* font;
    SDL_Color fg;
    std::stringstream s;
    SDL_Surface* ammoSurface;
    SDL_Texture* ammoText;
    SDL_Rect ammoRect;
    SDL_Surface* weaponSurface;
    SDL_Texture* weaponText;
    SDL_Rect weaponRect;
    //SDL_Surface* killedSurface;
    //SDL_Texture* killedText;
    //SDL_Rect killedRect;
    SDL_Surface* waveSurface;
    SDL_Texture* waveText;
    SDL_Rect waveRect;
};

void Player::Update()
{
    move();
    for(unsigned int c = 0; c < bullets.size(); c++)
    {
        bullets[c]->Update();
        bullets[c]->Render();
        if(bullets[c]->getAge() >= bullets[c]->getRange())
        {
            //Bullet* temp = bullets[c];
            bullets.erase(bullets.begin() + c);
            //delete temp;
        }
    }

    renderHUD();
}

void Player::Render(int _xOffset, int _yOffset)
{
    sprite->getRectByReference()->x = int(x);
    sprite->getRectByReference()->y = int(y);
    sprite->draw(int(x),int(y),_xOffset,_yOffset);
}

void Player::renderHUD()
{
    s.str(std::string());
    s.clear();

    s << *clips[weapon].getAmmo();
    ammoRect.w = s.str().size() * 32;
    ammoSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,s.str().c_str(),fg);
    ammoText = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,ammoSurface);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,ammoText,NULL,&ammoRect);

    s.str(std::string());
    s.clear();
    s << weaponNames[weapon];
    weaponRect.w = s.str().size() * 16;
    weaponSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,s.str().c_str(),fg);
    weaponText = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,weaponSurface);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,weaponText,NULL,&weaponRect);

    s.str(std::string());
    s.clear();
    s << "Wave: " << Main::wave;
    waveRect.w = s.str().size() * 16;
    waveSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,s.str().c_str(),fg);
    waveRect.x = gameWidth - waveRect.w;
    waveText = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,waveSurface);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,waveText,NULL,&waveRect);
}


Player::~Player(void)
{
    //delete xOffset  --- Not Deleting because it is a passed pointer, this variable is used in other classes;
    //delete yOffset  ---                                        ""                                          ;
    //delete sprite;    --- Not deleting because when deleted, I get a Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE.;
                      //I don't mind not deleting this because there is only one instance of this class, and I don't think
                      //this is what's causing the memory leak
    //delete screen;  --- Not deleting this because screen is used by most other classes, and is deleted in my main class
    for(unsigned int c = 0; c < bullets.size(); c++)
    {
        delete bullets[c];
    }

    TTF_CloseFont(font);
    SDL_FreeSurface(ammoSurface);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(ammoText);
    SDL_FreeSurface(weaponSurface);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(weaponText);
    //SDL_FreeSurface(killedSurface); ---I commented out every line of code involving this surface, it doesn't actually exist
    //SDL_DestroyTexture(killedText); ---I commented out every line of code involving this texture, it doesn't actually exist
    SDL_FreeSurface(waveSurface);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(waveText);
    TTF_Quit();
}

#pragma once

#include "destructive_reasoning.h"
#include "Screen.h"
#include "Sprite.h"
#include "Player.h"

class Main
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Use a memory leak detector (on Linux and MacOSX [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)....)

Comment: For Windows there is [VLD](http://vld.codeplex.com).

Comment: Use Raii to avoid resource leak.

Comment: Coming from a guy that knows zippo about SDL programming (so consider the source; me) `Player:: renderHUD` seems incorrect. Unless I'm totally in the dark about how SDL manages its resources (a distinct possibility) things like `ammoText = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,ammoSurface);` will happily lose the existing `ammoText` texture from a prior invoke. Again, i could be out-to-lunch, but that entire function just seems odd.

Comment: Narrow down your problem. Divide and conquer. Make a [testcase](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Your indentation is a mess.

Comment: @WhozCraig I just changed my code so that ammoText and all the other textures initialized by that function are created in that function(no longer global variables) and then I delete them at the end of the function. The memory leak is gone! The only problem is when I close the program, I get a first chance exception and unhandled exception due to access violation reading 0x00000008. What does that mean?

Comment: @user3084816 Generally a close-to-zero access violation means a NULL structure pointer with a data element N-bytes in (in your case N=8) is being dereferenced. Somewhere during shutdown you're dereferencing a NULL pointer. Running it under a debugger should easily spot where this is happening. Best of luck.

Comment: @user3084816 Are you still freeing up stuff in your destructor? I would take a look at it and maybe use a debugger to step through it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to free the `SDL_Surfaces` after using them to create a `SDL_Texture`.

```
void Player::renderHUD()
{
    // ...

    ammoSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,s.str().c_str(),fg);
    ammoText = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,ammoSurface);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,ammoText,NULL,&ammoRect);

    // Your prbolem is here, ammoSurface needs to be freed since it's already been copied into ammoText
    // Calling FreeSurface on ammoSurface will free it, but ammoText reamins intact
    SDL_FreeSurface(ammoSurface);

    // ....
}
```

And yes, this goes for every time you use `TTF_RenderText_Solid()`

Comment: And thanks a lot for the response, I know my code is all messy in the post and there was a lot of it, so I can imagine reading through was a pain in the butt. Sorry about that, I really appreciate the response though.

Comment: @user3084816 No problem. As for formaitng, indentation is 4 spaces here on SO. Don't use tabs.

Comment: I think that worked! Its certainly better than it was before. Now, the memory graph doesn't seem to increase as the game runs, but does decrease when it closes, but then slowly increases after the decrease(after the game is closed). Also, the game takes very long to close(it was like that before too), but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with memory leaks

Comment: @user3084816 You should check out other places where you allocate SDL_Surfaces, I assume you do the same thing with sprites and stuff? And if that doesn't work you should check your new/delete and consider replacing them with a smart pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I would turn my comment into an answer.

In your code you call

```
ammoSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,s.str().c_str(),fg);
ammoText = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,ammoSurface);
...
weaponSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,s.str().c_str(),fg);
weaponText = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,weaponSurface);
```

and

```
waveSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,s.str().c_str(),fg);
waveRect.x = gameWidth - waveRect.w;
waveText = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,waveSurface)
```

every frame, I would remove them from there, initialise them outwith of the render loop, update them in an update function and simply pass them in to the render loop as arguments, you will lose the memory leak: the reason being that you will create only one in-memory instance of each and then you can repeatedly use them as needed.

As a general rule, try and not create/destroy any objects in the render loop, tends to get big and messy fast.  Re-use will save a lot of ram and cycles.

I would have `lastAmmo`, `lastWave`, `lastWeapon` variables which hold the previous value of each, that way you can reference the values in the update loop and only generate a new texture for each **only** if the value has changed.  That way when you get into the render loop you have simply got some static render code to run the whole show.

### Memory leaks:

Whilst it is possible to use CRT to debug to track down memory leaks, I would recommend [**Visual Leak Detector**](http://vld.codeplex.com/): nice, straight-forward and integrates into Visual Studio 2008, 2010 and 2012.

### Pros:

- Integrated
- Simple usage (one include makes it functional)

### Cons:

- Can be really slow on large block leaks as it will display the whole leaked block

Hope this helps, if not let me know and I can add or amend to suit your needs:)